# Cannot run Visual Studio 2012 remote debugger on Windows Server 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2012, remote-debugging

I'm trying to run the Visual Studio 2012 remote debugger on a Windows Server 2008 x86 (not R2) virtual machine, but I can't get past the "Remote Debugging Configuration" screen as the Windows Web Services API fails to install with the following message

```
---------------------------
Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor
---------------------------
The Windows Web Services installer failed to execute. The installer exited with error 'Data of this type is not supported.'.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

The only thing that I have to go on are these two posts

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/5f6f20e5-67a7-43a3-a12f-42e1ef5dfec4#7ed3da49-5ba2-4cce-8ba7-889c5f273294
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/59cd9a67-d549-4169-906b-0bd95030011c

Which seem to indicate that the problem is simply that this update can't be downloaded from anywhere.  I've also tried to download these manually, however the only source I've found is [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wndp/archive/2009/10/09/final-version-of-windows-web-services-api-for-windows-xp-vista-server-2003-and-server-2008-is-now-available.aspx) which states that my company has to agree to some terms first, which is obviously a little too much effort just to get remote debugging working.

How can I get remote debugging working on a Windows Server 2008 (non-R2) machine?

**Update:** I have raised this on [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/763521/cannot-run-visual-studio-2012-remote-debugger-on-windows-server-2008-non-r2)

Comment: Exact same problem here, with the same conclusion - no support for remote debugging on Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008 due to dependency on WWS!

Comment: Same problem here, and the 2010 remote debugger will not work for 2012.

Comment: thanks for the reference to MS Connect... still not solved...

Answer (score 7):

There is a (somewhat long-winded) workaround for this issue.

1. If not already, install "Platform Update for Windows Server 2008 (KB971644)" from Window Update (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971644?wa=wsignin1.0). It will install KB971512, KB971513, and KB960362 in "Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Installed Updates".
2. Install Windows Live Essentials from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=255474

A dependency of the Live Essentials will install the WWS update that is required.

Hopefully this gets you unblocked until the issue can be fixed properly.

Comment: Just confirmed that this works, I'm going to try and hunt around to figure out what URL it uses to see if there is a way to download and install this separately from the Live Essentials pack.

Comment: Sorry if my post was ambiguous. As far as I understand, Live Essentials bundles the patch and there is no public download URL.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue on Windows Vista.

I discovered that someone has helpfully uploaded the WWSAPI installers here:
http://rw.internals.io/post/fix-remote-debugging-on-windows-vista-requires-wwsapi

Once I'd installed the appropriate WWSAPI, I could run MSVSMON.EXE directly with no need to install anything else.
Admittedly I am using Visual Studio 2015 rather than VS2012, but I expect that earlier versions would also work.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what i did to get remote debugging working on a server.

Use VS2010 remote debugger, copy the entire folder where its installed to your server.
Make sure that the user used to run msvsmon has the right privileges to debug your code

Comment: I tried that first, since I was already using the "Visual Studio 10 Remote Debugger" installed as a service (from using VS 2010); but it doesn't work from VS 2012. It doesn't see the VS 2010 remote debugger and shows a dialog box saying: "Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor named '2K8'.  The Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor (MSVSMON.EXE) does not appear to be running on the remote computer. This may be because a firewall is preventing communication to the remote computer. Please see Help for assistance on configuring remote debugging."

Answer (score -1):

As it says, the remote debugger for VS2010 only works with the Studio 2010.
For the VS 2012 you need to install VS2012 debugger which is found on the install disk under \RemoteTools\rtools_setup_x64.exe

Comment: My problem is with installing the VS2012 remote debugger - the VS2010 remote debugger works fine, however as you say it only works with VS2010 which means that I am currently resigned to performing most of my remote debugging with VS2010 as opposed to the shiny new VS2012